# General Oracle Results Table

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I am designing a new laboratory database.  I want all the raw results (for all tests) in one table (`RESULTS`).  However, the numerical values vary greatly in quantity and precision.  For example, some results are simply a whole number count, while other results come from highly sensitive equipment.

Which case below is ideal (and why)?

Option 1: Store each result in a `raw_result` column as a NUMBER with the highest precision allowed.

OR

Option 2: Create the `RESULTS` table and several child tables each representing results of a similar data type and a `raw_result` column as a NUMBER with a specific precision for that type.  (ie: integer from 1 to 1000, decimal number to 6 decimal places, etc)

Also, in a related post [General Oracle Data Collection Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040977/general-oracle-data-collection-storage), I asked about the ideal way to store raw signals in this database.

Comment: In my own opinion, option 1 would be much simpler to implement and maintain, but I would lose a lot of efficiency for storing small numbers in a large data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option 1. A NUMBER is a NUMBER internally to Oracle, regardless of precision and scale.

Option 2 appears to be a horrible maintenance nightmare from the get-go, and what do you do if you decide to change the precision of one of your values?

EDIT: to illustrate, consider:

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE testing (n1 NUMBER(38,12), n2 NUMBER(5));

    Table created
    SQL> INSERT INTO testing VALUES (1, 1);

    1 row inserted
    SQL> INSERT INTO testing VALUES (990, 9900);

    1 row inserted
    SQL> INSERT INTO testing VALUES (1999999.999999, 1);

    1 row inserted
    SQL> SELECT n1, DUMP(n1) n1d, n2, DUMP(n2) n2d FROM testing;

                   N1 N1D                                N2 N2D
--------------------- ------------------------------ ------ --------------------
       1.000000000000 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2                  1 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
     990.000000000000 Typ=2 Len=3: 194,10,91           9900 Typ=2 Len=2: 194,100
 1999999.999999000000 Typ=2 Len=8: 196,2,100,100,100      1 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
                      ,100,100,100                          
    SQL>
```

No difference in storage. The length stored is data dependent, not the precision/scale of the column definition.

[This link](http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/number_representation.htm) gives a pretty good explanation of how the NUMBER type is stored. It's not as simple as comparing the values to get an idea of how much storage it will take for a given number. For example, it takes 3 bytes to store the number 990, but only 2 bytes to store 9900.

Comment: Correct, with one note, you can only have a certain number of bytes, so different precision and scales may be needed for different numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here. If you're talking about prohibiting too much precision, that's one thing - Oracle can enforce that with NUMBER(p,s) definitions. But it all takes the same amount of storage.

Comment: My fault, I was thinking if you set a scale of say 5 it would always take the 5 bytes even if you gave it an integer.  Now that I think about it, I don't think that is the case.

Comment: So if I store the number 150 into a NUMBER(38,127) column, Oracle is smart enough to know it's a small integer with no decimal places and uses only a single byte to store it?

Comment: I'm amazed!  I always suspected number data types were statically sized as in most programming languages.

Comment: It's counterintuitive in sense that the size of a NUMBER is more closely aligned with the number of significant digits stored than the magnitude of the number. Think of a NUMBER as being stored in scientific notation and it helps.

Comment: I know that a 'single' or 'double' in C/C++ is scientific notation, but completely base-2 (not base-10).  Surely, Oracle had a good reason for keeping numbers more in decimal notation.

Comment: I would have to guess that it has to do with avoiding precision issues that come with binary representations of floats.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends how you're going to use the data later on. Option 1 will be easier to set up initially, but if you're then going to always be trying to separate the data for processing/display etc later on, then Option 2 might be easier in the long run.

DCookie has done a good job in explaining that Option 2 has no technical benefits for storage. It therefore boils down to whatever processing you're going to be doing with it.

> I want all the raw results (for all tests) in one table (`RESULTS`).

If your feeling is that it makes most sense to put it all in one table, then do that.